# htmlTemplate don't work for symfony/mailer

Tags: php, symfony, twig, html-templates, symfony-mailer

I'm using the `"symfony/mailer": "6.1.*"` package in a Symfony application to send the mails.

My function use HTML template like the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#twig-html-css):

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;

public function index(MailerInterface $mailer,Exception $exception): Response
{
     $email = (new Email())
         ->from('from@example.com')
         ->to('to@example.com')
         ->subject('Symfony Mailer!')
         ->htmlTemplate('_mail/exception-de-base.html.twig')
         ->context([
            'code' => $exception->getCode(),
            'heureDate' => (new DateTime())->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'),
            'file' => $exception->getFile(),
            'line' => $exception->getLine(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
         ])
     ;
     $mailer->send($email);
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error:

`Attempted to call an undefined method named "htmlTemplate" of class "Symfony\Component\Mime\Email".`

In my editor, the `use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;` has the gray color, that means it is not called.

My PHP version is 8.1 and I use:

```
"symfony/twig-bundle": "6.1.*",
"twig/cssinliner-extra": "^3.4",
"twig/extra-bundle": "^3.4",
"twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `$email = (new TemplatedEmail())`

Comment: @Perhaps Thenk you

Comment: This is the second time you thanked me which is nice but be aware that stackoverflow frowns on simple thank you comments.  Which is probably why your first one got deleted.  I might add that someone did take the time to write a full answer.  Perhaps you could extend your gratitude to them as well by accepting their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#html-content)

> To define the contents of your email with Twig, **use the
> TemplatedEmail class**. This class extends the normal Email class but
> **adds some new methods for Twig templates**

So you should be able to solve your error with:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;

$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
    ->from('fabien@example.com')
    ->to(new Address('ryan@example.com'))
    ->subject('Thanks for signing up!')

    // path of the Twig template to render
    ->htmlTemplate('emails/signup.html.twig')

    // pass variables (name => value) to the template
    ->context([
        'expiration_date' => new \DateTime('+7 days'),
        'username' => 'foo',
    ])
;
```